# Background Color Cant be set?

Tags: html, css

[image]

````
<div class="container" ng-app="sortApp" ng-controller="mainController">
                    <form>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <div style="color:white;background-color:#f78800;border-color:#f78800;" class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></div>
                                    <input style="width:855px;"type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..." ng-model="searchFish">
                            </div>      
                        </div>
                    </form>

                <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="hotkey">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <a style="color:#f78800;font-weight:bold;font-size:15px;">KEY</a>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <a style="color:#f78800;font-weight:bold;font-size:15px;">ON FOOT</a>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <a style="color:#f78800;font-weight:bold;font-size:15px;">ON VEHICLE</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="roll in sushi | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | filter:searchFish">
                            <td>{{ roll.name }}</td>
                            <td>{{ roll.fish }}</td>
                            <td>{{ roll.tastiness }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>

                </table>
                </div>
    ```
    ```
#hotkey {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 900px;
}

#hotkey td, #hotkey th {
  border: 2px solid #f78800;
  padding: 8px;
}

#hotkey td {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}
````

```
angular.module('sortApp', [])

.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
  $scope.sortType     = 'name'; // set the default sort type
  $scope.sortReverse  = false;  // set the default sort order
  $scope.searchFish   = '';     // set the default search/filter term

  // create the list of sushi rolls 
  $scope.sushi = [
    { name: 'Cali Roll', fish: 'Crab', tastiness: 2 },
    { name: 'Philly', fish: 'Tuna', tastiness: 4 },
    { name: 'Tiger', fish: 'Eel', tastiness: 7 },
    { name: 'Rainbow', fish: 'Variety', tastiness: 6 }
  ];

});
```

So , the odd line has a white background , how do i change the background to transparent ? for example row 1 , row 3 , the background color is white , i just try to add background-color on any style but its seems not working , every odd seems has a background here , id like to change it to transparent

```js
angular.module('sortApp', [])

.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
  $scope.sortType     = 'name'; // set the default sort type
  $scope.sortReverse  = false;  // set the default sort order
  $scope.searchFish   = '';     // set the default search/filter term
  
  // create the list of sushi rolls 
  $scope.sushi = [
    { name: 'Cali Roll', fish: 'Crab', tastiness: 2 },
    { name: 'Philly', fish: 'Tuna', tastiness: 4 },
    { name: 'Tiger', fish: 'Eel', tastiness: 7 },
    { name: 'Rainbow', fish: 'Variety', tastiness: 6 }
  ];
  
});
```

```css
#hotkey {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 900px;
}

#hotkey td, #hotkey th {
  border: 2px solid #f78800;
  padding: 8px;
}

#hotkey td {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" ng-app="sortApp" ng-controller="mainController">
     <form>
      <div class="form-group">
       <div class="input-group">
        <div style="color:white;background-color:#f78800;border-color:#f78800;" class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></div>
         <input style="width:855px;"type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..." ng-model="searchFish">
       </div>      
      </div>
     </form>
  
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="hotkey">
     <thead>
      <tr>
       <td>
        <a style="color:#f78800;font-weight:bold;font-size:15px;">KEY</a>
       </td>
       <td>
        <a style="color:#f78800;font-weight:bold;font-size:15px;">ON FOOT</a>
       </td>
       <td>
        <a style="color:#f78800;font-weight:bold;font-size:15px;">ON VEHICLE</a>
       </td>
      </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="roll in sushi | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | filter:searchFish">
       <td>{{ roll.name }}</td>
       <td>{{ roll.fish }}</td>
       <td>{{ roll.tastiness }}</td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
    
    </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi, I just added your posted code in the code snippet and its working fine. The reason is why this is working fine, because of some style properties are missing and which make the table rows styling. Are you using bootstrap in your project ?

Comment: yeah , im using bootstrap , is that the problem ?

Comment: MIght be, I posted the answer below have a look and try to remove `table-striped` property. if still not any success then we can debug the UI issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked closely to your code and I think you are using bootstrap and you are also using some table classes like `table-striped` which can cause the style which is an issue for you

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/content/tables/#striped-rows have a look at the documentation

So the solution, in my opinion, is to remove the style property `table-striped` and try.

Comment: yeah , i just remove table-striped and its works fine , thanks